# Object destructuring when creating new objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object: `parsedData = {head: {fullName: 'John Doe'}}`
I want to create a new object and do smth like this, but my destructuring skills proven useless (ahem):

```
const obj = {{fullName}: parsedData.head}
obj.fullName // 'John Doe'
```

Comment: `const obj =  parsedData.head` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a use-case for destructuring as far as I can tell.

Comment: `const obj = {...parsedData.head}`
destructuring is used to get properties from object, not to set them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention specifically wanting to *create a new object*. If by that you mean that `obj` should not reference `parsedData.head`, then you can use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
const obj = { ...parsedData.head };
// obj = { fullName: 'John Doe' }
// obj !== parsedData.head
```

Otherwise, if you don't care whether `obj` references `parsedData.head`, you don't need any destructuring or spread syntax at all:

```
const obj = parsedData.head;
// obj = { fullName: 'John Doe' }
// obj === parsedData.head
```